# How do I expand the margins in my pdf in R markdown?

Tags: r

I am knitting a file to pdf in r markdown and have a page with 6 plots.  I've adjusted using the margins and size using the par() function but the plots on the 2nd page only take up about 1/2 of the page.  How do I get them to use more of the length of the page?

Here is my code:

```
#R program to compare the exact and asymptotic distribution
#of sample mean from i.i.d. ga(alpha,lambda) distribution


#Use ga(alpha=2,lambda=1) --> mean=2, var=2
y<-seq(from=0, to=5, by=0.01)

#Create function for the exact pdf
exact<-function(y,n,alpha,lambda){
   ((lambda^(alpha*n))/gamma(n*alpha))*(n*y)^(alpha*n-1)*exp(-lambda*n*y)*n
    }

#Different values of sample size to compare
n<-c(1,2,5,10,30,50)
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
par(cex=0.5, mai=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1))

for(i in 1:length(n)){
#true distribution
    plot(y,exact(y,n=n[i],alpha=2,lambda=1),col="red",type='l',main=paste(
          "Gamma(2,1), n=",n[i]),ylab='pdf',xaxt = "n")



#approximate distribution
lines(y,dnorm(y,mean=2,sd=sqrt(2/n[i])),type='l', col="blue",xlab="")

legend(x="topright",col=c("red","blue"),legend=c("Exact Distribution",
                                                    "Approximate Distribution"),
       pch=5)
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHg5e.png)

Comment: You'll have to change the value of the code chunk option `fig.height`, see https://yihui.org/knitr/options/. So this won't be solved by changing the code you've shared!

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  ```fig.height=10``` worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad this helped!